# Local Maxima Detection on 3D Voxel Structure (3D numpy arrays)

Tags: deep-learning, 3d, max, voxel

We start with a 3d voxel (or 3d array) of size 24x24x24 all made by 0s, but in some arbitrary indexes we have set 1s. After sending this voxel to a deep neural network we get back the same voxel-like structure, but this time each of the voxels contains a scalar that represents the probability output of each voxel being a 0 (low probability) or a 1 (some number close to 1).

Within this distribution, we expect (and actually see) that the highest probabilities are distributed **around** the actual indexes from the input data that correspond to 1s. These, conform small 3d gradients that go from 0 to close to 1.

Given all this, I want to find a method/algorithm to distinguish in the prediction these groups from the noise. My final goal is to get the indexes of the max value within the groups and among groups, so that I can reconstruct my original 3d voxel, with the 1s placed where they should or at least, as close as possible. Is there anything already implemented I can try for this purpose?

P.D. The 1s in the original voxels can be close to each other.

We have already tried:

- Selecting the index of those voxels that were over an arbitrary threshold.
- Setting a kernel of size n x n x n, mapping the prediction voxel and keeping only the highest values within them.
- Using Gaussian Mixture models.

None of them have worked at the level we expect (+90-95% precision)